# Rock-paper-scissors in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, game, rock-paper-scissors

I'm relatively new to C++, and have attempted a Rock Paper Scissors game, and it works. Here and there I added some countdowns so that the program doesn't run instantly. Any tips for improving the program even further, or maybe even something to add a further level of complexity to the game to make it better?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

void instructions()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "1) ROCK!\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "2) PAPER!\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "3) SCISSORS!\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Shoot! ";
    
}
int main()
{
    int userWins = 0;
    int computerWins = 0;

    int gamesCount = 0;

    //assign gamesCount = user input

    std::cout << "============================================================================\n";
    std::cout << "Welcome! Thank you for playing a game of rock, paper, and scissors with me!  \n";
    std::cout << "Please choose one of the following options: \n";
    std::cout << "============================================================================\n";

    while ((gamesCount < 10) && (userWins <= 3) && (computerWins <= 3) && (userWins <= computerWins + 2) && (computerWins != userWins + 2))
    {
        ++gamesCount;

        srand(time(NULL));
        int computer = rand() % 3 + 1;
        int user = 0;

        instructions();

        std::cin >> user;
        if ((user == 1 && computer == 3) || (user == 2 && computer == 1) || (user == 3 && computer == 2))
        {
            std::cout << "You win!\n";
            ++userWins;
        }
        else if ((user == 1 && computer == 2) || (user == 2 && computer == 3) || (user == 3 && computer == 1))
        {
            std::cout << "Computer win!\n";
            ++computerWins;
        }
        else if (user == computer)
        {
            std::cout << "Tied\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error, please use and input between 1-3\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Your score is currently " << userWins << ", Computer score is " << computerWins << "\n";
        std::cout << "============================================================================\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Your final score is " << userWins << ", whereas the Computer's final score is " << computerWins << "\n";

    if (userWins > computerWins)
    {
        std::cout << "You have succesfully beat the computer! Congratulations!\n";
    }
    else if (userWins < computerWins)
    {
        std::cout << "Unfortunately the computer has bested you!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "DRAW! What a close game!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are asking about ways to add further complexity to the game, you may want to try implementing [Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_paper_scissors#Additional_weapons). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't repeat yourself.
The `instructions` function does the same thing 4 times, changing only one string.  Make the thing you want to do *for each string* the code, just once.  Then drive it in a loop with the data.  E.g.

```
const char* lines[] = {
    "1) ROCK!", "2) PAPER!", "3) SCISSORS!", "Shoot! " };
for (const auto& s : lines) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

---

It's good that `instructions` are a clearly separated subroutine, that is, a named function.  But I was disappointed to see that the file continued with `main` and no other organization.

You should separate things out into functions more comprehensively.  Don't put everything in `main` down to fine detail; rather, call a series of high-level descriptively named functions, possibly looping over the main logic, but no details on how any of that works.

---

The old C library random numbers are pretty poor.  Look into using the C++ random number library.

---

```
       if ((user == 1 && computer == 3) || (user == 2 && computer == 1) || (user == 3 && computer == 2))
    ⋮
        else if ((user == 1 && computer == 2) || (user == 2 && computer == 3) || (user == 3 && computer == 1))
```

These two long comparisons are basically the same thing, comparing the priority of two moves.  Make a general purpose function that returns this.  The logic only needs to be in one place, and done once.

I'd suggest making it an enumeration type, since it's not a number with the normal meaning of arithmetic, and it helps keep type checking for the variable usage.  This becomes very good to have in more complex programs.

```
enum RPS_t { Rock=1, Paper=2, Scissors=3 };

⋮

bool operator< (RPS_t left, RPS_t right) // true if left LOSES to right
{ ... }
```

Now you can simply ask `if(computer<user)`.  But note that you cover all three possibilities: so test for tie first, since that's easiest.  Then test for user winning, and then if it's not either of those it *must* be the computer winning, and you don't have to check the math separately for that case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify that win-loss condition - it could be a single line.  First subtract 1 from each result (can be done behind the scenes for the user, and the computer just doesn't add 1 to its choice) so you're dealing with `0 = ROCK`, `1 = PAPER`, `2 = SCISSORS`.  Then the formula is simply:

```
result = (user - computer + 3) % 3;
```

If `result == 0`, it's a tie.

If `result == 1`, the user wins.

If `result == 2`, the computer wins.

This could all be handled in a switch statement:

```
switch(result)
{
    case 0:
        std::cout << "Tie!\n";
        break;
    case 1:
        std::cout << "You win!\n";
        userWins++;
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "Computer wins!\n";
        computerWins++;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Why subtract 1 from each result?  That seems unnecessary.  If anything, I'd be adding 3 to the `user` value, so that the difference is always positive, and we don't need to consider a negative `%`.

Comment: @TobySpeight That would work too, I just prefer to stick to 0-indexed values when possible, to avoid confusion.  When I tested it, the negative `%`s worked properly, but it may depend on the compiler?  At any rate, something along these lines is clearly better than the series of `X == Y` statements in the OP.

Comment: Oh yes, definitely a better form of comparison: much easier to read and maintain.  The rules for `/` (and therefore `%`) changed in C99 from being implementation-defined to rounding the quotient towards zero.  That means that the remainder tends to be negative when numerator and denominator have different signs.  `-1 % 3` yields -1 here with both `gcc -std=c89` and `gcc -std=c17`.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M5MP1M5az

Comment: Of course, we can handle that with `case 1: case -2: // player wins`.

Comment: @TobySpeight I added a `+3` in there to avoid ambiguity.  Guess I was still working in a C/Java mindset there.

Answer (score 1):

It is good that you validate the user's choice to be between 1 and 3 but see what happens if you enter an alphabetic value:

[image]

Consider creating a function to validate the input and clear out any errors like the following:

```cpp
bool enterNumber(int& value, int minVal, int maxVal)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        std::cin >> value;
        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            if (std::cin.eof())
                return false;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout << "Please enter a number only.\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (value < minVal || value > maxVal) 
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a number between " << minVal << " and " << maxVal << ".\n";
            continue;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And replacing `std::cin >> user;` with the following:

```cpp
if (!enterNumber(user, 1, 3)) {
    std::cout << "Failed to get input\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: That's a general issue for almost every "simple" program we see that takes input from the user.  I think your code will object if the user _starts_ with a letter, but will simply stop reading when it sees a letter if it saw digits first, but leave the rest for the next read, even though it won't see anything until it is ENTERed.

Comment: @JDługosz, do you have suggestions for handling this better?

Comment: @JohanduToit Advise I read some 35 years ago:  "Don't treat your user like an input file."  For your specific function, I think it should read a whole line as a string and then parse it.  In the old days, make sure the parse took the whole thing; with the newer functions this is natural behavior.  As a general issue, I think that there should be a simple-to-use _forms_ library that will do robust input of a group of fields, that includes a plain terminal implementation.  These issues just get in the way of learning to write the real code belonging to the problem.

Comment: (cont) Students should be taught to write their problem as a _function_ taking input and returning results, with I/O separate.  Don't make him start with a blank file, but give him a main program with command line arguments and test-case driver, and the function declared with an empty body `/* put your logic here*/`.  That will allow them to concentrate on the problem without overwhelming distractions, and expose them to good practices.  You won't have to _explain_ separation of concerns, testing, etc. it will just be there in the file.

Comment: That's pretty good - and you've now separated the error reporting from valid return values, too.  To be honest, that's around the point you should be posting it as a question, for proper review.  The only thing I would change would be for the `main()` to return a small positive value (probably `EXIT_FAILURE`) rather than -1 in the error case.